# Signing in with the correct mail and password shows me another YT channel

Tags: gmail, youtube, google-account, youtube-channel

I have a problem. When I enter the email and password of the old channel, it showed another one than the one I want. How is that possible?

That channel I want to subscribe to is still alive, but with current email and password, I cant enter.

It's like merging two channels into one. Same email, or different channels and Gmail emails.

It's been a long time, I don't remember what I did. Please help!

Comment: Welcome. Is that email address the primary email address of your Google account or a secondary email address? Do your account have only one channel or multiple channels?

Comment: @Rubén, thank you for answering. Well, I don't know, I created this a long time ago. That channel had one as a subchannel But I don't know where the first one, the real one, was lost.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing "channel" with a brand account and "subchannel" with a channel. I suggest you to look into the Youtube Help to learn about brand accounts and channels.